# it's contain or it contains?

Tags: verb-forms

Whats
 the difference between the following sentences :

> For now it's contain the following features:

and

> For now it contains the following features:

I know that this is a simple question but some times i find problem with that!

Comment: The first is ungrammatical because it misuses a possessive pronoun.  You could rephrase to make ***its*** fit by saying something like:  "For now its contents includes the following features:"

Comment: @Jim Yeah, or `For now its containing the following features` right?

Comment: No.  that would also be incorrect.

Comment: @Jim mmm,so  why?

Comment: *Its* is like *my, your, his, her, their,* etc.

Comment: well it would need to be ***it's*** but even after you fixed that, "it is containing" to mean "it contains" is quite awkward.   I might only use "it is containing" in the sense of "holding back": What's it doing?  It is containing the overflow; keeping it from spilling onto the floor."

Comment: @Jim Shouldn't that be "for now its contents **include** the following features?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singular non-personal neuter pronoun in English is *it*.  The word *it* will be the subject of the sentence and a verb will typically follow.

> For now it contains the following features:

*Possessive* non-personal neuter pronoun is *its*.  A noun will follow *its*, not a verb.

> She gave me the video game cartridge and I looked for its spot on the shelf.

*It's* is short for *it is*.

> What is that?  It's a book!